# Laravel eloquent: how to use "where" when receive multiple ID?

Tags: laravel

Assume I want to build a music playList page. Each of the playlist's item have **music_name** and **album_picture**.

[something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBICX.png)

But both music_name and album_picture are coming from different tables (etc. music, album ) and use album_id as key for one-to-many relationship.

How can I get those data in laravel?

I know that I can do the following, when I only need "one" :

```
$music = Music::where('album_id', $request->query('album_id'))->get();
$album = Album::where('album_id', $request->query('album_id'))->get();
```

But Now I need a play list, so I got **"multiple"** album_id.

Any Idea how to do this?

---

**my table looks like:**

music:

id, album_id, name, length, source, created_at, updated_at

album： 
id, name, picture, year, description, author, created_at, updated_at

Comment: You should use `join` for getting value from different table. Show you table how it looks?

Comment: Music table's album_id is foriegnkey key of Album table?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud  Okay, I add my table.

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd yes, I add my table, if you want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$album = DB::table('album')
           ->select('album.picture as album_picture','music.name as music_name')
           ->leftJoin('music','album.id','=','music.album_id')
           ->get();
```

Comment: This seems a great way. what if I what to show "singles" when album_id is null?

Comment: Please check my updated answer
It will list all the albumbs and related music records

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = Model::whereIn('album_id', $album_ids_array)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is using relationships in your models, in this case you can create two models(music and album)

then in your music model add the next function

```
public function album(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Album');
}
```

and next in your controller you can do something like

```
$music = Music::with('album')->find(put_here_music_id);
```

You may also call the find method with an array of primary keys

```
$musics = Music::with('album')->find([1,2,3]);
```

and it will return a collection from music with their album.

Don't forget to add in your controller

```
use App\Music;
```

More about relationships
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Thanks for reply,  "with" also a great way :)